# Why fires the updated observer before the created observer?

Tags: laravel

In the current Laravel application, I manage projects which have a folder for a file.

On store project, the created observer is called to create the folder. Till now, it works well.

On project update, i like to update the folder name to have the folder_name = project_name.

But if i use both observers, the updated observer is called before the created observer. To show it, I implemented the `echo`function.

Controller:

```
    public function store(StoreProjectRequest $request)
    {
        $project = $request->user()->projectsAsCreator()->create($request->all());

        $projectPermission = new ProjectPermissionController();

        $projectPermission->createPermissions('view', $project->id, [$request->user()->id]);

        $projectPermission->createPermissions('edit', $project->id, [$request->user()->id]);

        $projectPermission->createPermissions('admin', $project->id, [$request->user()->id]);

        event(new ProjectCreated($project));

        return response()->json(new ProjectCollectionResource($project));
    }
```

Model methods

```
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($project) {
            self::setProjectNumber($project);
            self::createProjectFolder($project);
            self::updateProject($project);
            echo '1';
        });

        static::updated(function ($project) {
            echo '2';
            self::updateFolder($project);
        });
    }

    public static function updateProject($project)
    {
        $project->update([
            'due_date_status'           => self::getDueDateStatus($project),
            'due_date_status_label'     => self::getDueDateStatusLabel($project),
            'issue_labels'              => self::getIssueLabels($project->issues)
        ]);
    }
```

Response

```
2{
    "message": "Trying to get property 'objectable' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/gopanel/sites/7industry_net/public/7app/app/Models/Project/ProjectMethod.php",
    "line": 141,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/gopanel/sites/7industry_net/public/7app/app/Models/Project/ProjectMethod.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

As we can see, there is onli the number 2 in the response.

Why there is not the number one first? It means, why does the created observer not fire before the updated observer?

Comment: 1st one will fire when model instance create some data  and 2nd one will send while update so at same time you cannot get both response `echo`

Comment: the echo response is only to see, which one fires first. unfortunately, the 2. fires first. If i comment `self::updateFolder($project);` the response is 221

Comment: what are you doing in `updateProject($project)`?

Comment: @lagbox: i added it

Comment: which is causing an update event to fire? so you are seeing the 2 for an update because you are causing update events before you echo 1 in the created listener ... maybe

Comment: You `echo 1` after you call `updateProject` which will update the project and fire the updated event and then the crated event will finish. However this is very inefficient since you're running 2 operations. I would suggest you use a `creating` event to modify the model before it is actually saved to the database (and don't call `update` just modify the attributes)

Comment: But later on, i need the update observer to update the project folder.